# Scheduled task (sending an mail) in Laravel 5.6 is not executed

Tags: php, laravel

I try to send an email to my users who has unread items, once a day. For that, using Laravel 5.6, I'm scheduling a closure as follow:

```
use DB;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\UnreadLinks;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function() {
            $unreadLinks = DB::table('links')
                  ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'links.recipient_id')
                  ->select('users.email')
                  ->where('links.read_at', null)
                  ->groupBy('users.email')
                  ->get();

            foreach ($unreadLinks as $unreadLink) {
                Mail::to($unreadLink->email)->send(new UnreadLinks());
            }
        })->dailyAt('20:00');
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not receive any email.

- The query works well when debugged
- The mail is successfully sent when tried locally with Mailtrap
- Mailgun is correctly set up and works well with other parts of my app
- I set up the cron on my server following the Laravel documentation, and other jobs for other websites are running well
- I do not have any error log written (neither in file on server, nor by email with the `emailOutputTo` method)

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out why : the time asked in `dailyAt('20:00')` is 2 hours in the future relative to the server's time.

To get it to work perfectly, I had to set the `dailyAt` to **18:00**.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake, I guess it could be useful to other people

Comment: So it did get executed?

Comment: @user1491032, yep.